# Best way to implement a "parental help/feedback" during child training in a GA+NN

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I am work actually on a machine learning system using : GA (Genetics Algorithm) + NN (Neural Network) using native Python.

*Concerning the NN part:*

All NN are multi layered neural network (inspired by [this](https://medium.com/technology-invention-and-more/how-to-build-a-multi-layered-neural-network-in-python-53ec3d1d326a)), the layers topology (number of neurons inside each layer and the number of layers) are randomly chose initially, then each NN are train (Reinforcement Learning) with the same training data.
All NN have the exact same number of input and output, but not the same deep layer topology.

*Concerning the GA part:*

The population is composed by list of trained multi layered NN

I confront population to the "reality" [reality is a list of life frame, the reality is encoded as pandas data-frame where each line is corresponding to a frame (I use the frame as NN input) ], and depending on the NN output, the individual will act or not.

After that all frames are treated, I note the population ( relatively to the action), then make selection, keep elite, generate random new NN but also apply reproduction scheme via GA to generate new childs NN.

Child NN will herit the layer topology of one of the parent and genetics of the mix of the parents (with alteration via cross over and mutation)

All children will then be trained (with the same training data than parents) then I confront them to the reality then note each children etc... and do that generation after generation.

I expect that this work, because the note will increase generation after generation

---

I hope to implement something like parental education: I expect that children will be "helped/or receive live feedback" by parent :

- during a part of the child NN reinforcement learning procedure in order to "optimize" how the child neuronal weight are change during child training procedure.
- during the phase where the child NN is confront to the reality

---

Anyone could share some source, or share feedback if already work on this kind of implementation ? 
Do you think it may help to increase learning efficiency or it is absolutely un-usefull ?

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.  This appears too broad and high-level for Stack Overflow; perhaps post to the stats group?

Comment: Thank for the comment, in my opinion: it is no math, no stats, no biology subject, it is machine learning [ NN+GA ]  subject. It is finally a devs question, who (except devs) will work on NN+GA ? I really hope this question will not be close too soon, in order that someone may potentially help me... but I have already noted that GA+NN relative questions are quickly closed on StackOverflow... According to you what is the best place to ask this kind of question ?

Comment: Right; these questions are almost always about system design, rather than the focused implementation questions that fit under SO's charter.  Ironically, "where should I ask this question" is similarly off topic: asking for an off-site resource.  I can't help here, as I take *my* questions on this order to my local data scientists; I don't know of a convenient DL discussion site where this fits.  I'd have to do a loose search, the same problem that faces you.  Perhaps someone else will notice this and have a handy link?